# How do I assess the significance of classification accuracy, after determining hyperparameters with GridSearchCV and testing with train_test_split?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, scikit-learn, hyperparameter, permutation-test

So I've recently learned that if I use GridSearchCV to select the best hyperparameters AND evaluate model performance, this can lead to an optimistically biased measure of performance due to overfitting (Cawley, G.C.; Talbot, N.L.C. On over-fitting in model selection and subsequent selection bias in performance evaluation. J. Mach. Learn. Res 2010,11, 2079-2107.). Here's how I had originally run that, using a permutation test to assess significance of the (overestimated) classification accuracy:

```
def classify_high_low(X, y):

  # shuffle
  X, y = shuffle(X, y) 
  
  # specify model
  svm_model = SVC()
  sc = StandardScaler()
  pipeline = make_pipeline(sc, svm_model)

  param_grid = {
      'svc__C': np.logspace(-6,6,30), 
      'svc__gamma': np.logspace(6,-6,30), 
      'svc__kernel': ['rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid']
  }

  cv_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
  cv_search.fit(X,y)
  
  # update pipeline with new estimator
  pipeline = cv_search.best_estimator_
  
  # run permutation test
  score, p_scores, p = permutation_test_score(
      pipeline, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=5, n_permutations=1000)

  return score, p_scores, p, cv_search
```

After my revelation, I set aside a separate testing set, ran GridSearchCV on the training set to determine the best hyperparameters, and evaluated the final model with the left out testing set:

```
def classify_high_low(X, y):
    
    # Split the data into training/testing subsets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0, stratify=y)
    
    # specify model
    svm_model = SVC()
    sc = StandardScaler()
    pipeline = make_pipeline(sc, svm_model)
    
    param_grid = {
        'svc__C': np.logspace(-6,6,30), 
        'svc__gamma': np.logspace(6,-6,30), 
        'svc__kernel': ['rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid']
    }
    
    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    # Update pipeline with best model
    pipeline = clf.best_estimator_
    y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)

    return accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

But - this just returns a single accuracy score, and the result of this obviously depends on the split in train_test_split. I'm not quite sure how to overcome the potential bias in this (fairly arbitrary) split, or if I could assess this with some sort of permutation

So is it possible to combine a search for the best hyperparameters with gridsearch, evaluate the model performance with a left out testing set, and run some sort of permutation test to assess classification accuracy?

Thanks